# Where is the information stored when adding the reference to project?

Tags: visual-studio, reference, ide

I am using Visual Studio and adding reference to the project. I can find that there is a folder called References and i add the dll's or Projects to it.

Before build if i wanted to move it, which physical path or part of coding can i find the references.

After Build i can find that the references are converted to dll's but wanted to know before build, if it is stored somewhere. IF so where is it stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project references are stored in your project file.  For example in my .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyOtherProject\MyOtherProject.csproj">
    <Project>{9deefd25-a349-4244-b123-ed66927e7414}</Project>
    <Name>MyOtherProject</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can view your project file by opening it in another text editor, or by right clicking on it in VS and clicking Unload Project.  Then right click on the unloaded project and click Edit.  When you're done looking, right click and click Reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a project reference to another project and then you physically (or manually) move this project to another location (by copy/paste) then you will need to update the reference in your project. But, don't worry even if you fail to remember to update the reference Visual Studio will complain about it when compiling. But, if the reference is an assembly reference, then a copy will be created in your *Refences*/*bin* folder.

Comment: yeah, for example i have a reference in .NET of reference say stdole in references i have added the reference to it. i can find it in references but nowhere when i searched for it in the entire solution i could find any word or in the file paths of folder i could find it. Wanted to know how and where it is or understand its working mechanism.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand. Can you see the DLL in the "References" folder and you want to know its physical location/path in the file system?

Comment: since stdole is already a .net reference there wont be any dll. but not understanding how it is mapped. no search results when searched for stdole or no dlls in bin or obj locations.

Comment: i can see a rectangle box with the references in the references folder. but its virtual i guess. i wanted to understand the physical storage or otherwise the mapping of the references in the project

Comment: Can you right-click it and select Properties? You might be able to see the physical path?

Comment: it is showing some thing like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\stdole.dll which is common for all projects.. but in this case without opening the project i cannot find the references that too is virtual.

Comment: That's because it is part of the .NET Framework which by default it is already registered in the GAC. Obviously if you are deploying your project to a different machine that already has the .NET Framework installed, then you don't need to deploy this dll. Can you imagine having to deploy all DLLs to production or staging server?